# JQuery Combine Each with Live

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of divs that are updated with Ajax calls (It's MVC, but the HTML looks something like this when it's done):

```
<div class="progresswrapper running" id = "ProgressWrapper1"></div>
<div class="progresswrapper running" id = "ProgressWrapper2"></div>
```

Then the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

 var timerid = window.setInterval(function () {
            $('.progresswrapper.running').each(function () {
                 UpdateDivWithDataFromServer();
                 if(I'm done with this div) {
                    $(this).removeClass("running");
                 }
            });
        }, 500);
```

Is it possible to do this somehow?

Comment: use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), live is deprecated.

Comment: You'll have to provide the `UpdateDivWithDataFromServer` if you want us to fix whatever's wrong, the `removeClass` has to run in the oncomplete method of the ajax call.

Comment: Your current code is pretty much the only way to do it other than using the success callback of the ajax request that loads the content or a global ajax event. `.live` and `.on` only react to events. Using the ajax success is the most efficient way to handle it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var timerid = window.setInterval(function () {
$('.progresswrapper.running').each(function () {
    UpdateDivWithDataFromServer();
});
}, 500);

$(document).on("ajaxComplete",function(){
    $('.progresswrapper.running').each(function () {
         if(I'm done with this div) {
             $(this).removeClass("running");
         }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if()` statement needs to be inside the AJAX success callback, or inside an [`.ajaxStop()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) handler.

```
var timerid = window.setInterval(function () {
        $('.progresswrapper.running').each(function () {
             UpdateDivWithDataFromServer();
        });
    }, 500);
$('.progresswrapper').ajaxStop(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("running");
});
```